# Custom Domain for App Engine App Wrongly Pointing to SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have an App Engine App at http://1.lyfekit.appspot.com/ and I want to use the custom domain http:// www. lyfekit .com/

I verified the domain and added it to app engine app settings. I added the CNAME record www pointing to ghs.googlehosted .com

BUT, http:// www. lyfekit .com/ is going to https: //lyfekit .com/ and is giving me an SSL error. I do not need https. I simply want http.

The way I understand, if I am not using https, I do not need to configure a Google Apps Account for the domain.

Comment: Can you post your app.yaml?

Comment: Please find the app.yaml here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7jQ6w2N2zAGdllVbUJ4Y0MwTWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is a protocol. It's totally separate from a domain name. 
Somewhere in your app.yaml or web.xml file you have specified that you want a connection to be secure. App Engine follows your instructions and tries to use HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP protocol. Remove these instructions, and App Engine will stop using HTTPS

Comment: Please find [the app.yaml here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7jQ6w2N2zAGdllVbUJ4Y0MwTWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have done but the default module for your app (the one which your domain is mapped to) can be seen here:

http://lyfekit.appspot.com

and as you can see it redirects to https (because it will have secured:always set in the app.yaml file).

With your original URL you are specifying a particular version of your app (version 1) but as you can see by accessing the main appspot domain that version is not set as the default version.